# How to determine number of function/builtin/callable parameters programmatically?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, python-3.x, callable

I want to be able to classify an unknown function/builtin/callable based on its number of arguments.

I may write a piece of code like that:

```
if numberOfParameters(f) == 0:
    noParameters.append(f)
elif numberOfParameters(f) == 1:
    oneParameter.append(f)
else:
    manyParameters.append(f)
```

but I have no idea how to implement `numberOfParameters()`.  `inspect.getargspec` does not work with builtins. I can not use exceptions, since it is potentially expensive to call the function.

It would be great if the solution work with both Python 2.7 and Python 3.3+

Comment: Did you try ``help(...)``? E.g. for ``sorted``, it contains: ``sorted(iterable, cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False)``.

Comment: @jbndlr That would require parsing the docstring... I'm not sure if you would want to go down that rabbithole.

Comment: @jbndlr I need to do it programatically. Updated the question.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga he didn't mention to do it programmatically (before his edit), I didn't think one would want to do this for builtins from the code.

Comment: Bite the bullet and assemble a dictionary keyed by builtins (at least those which you care about) and whose values is the information that you want? It shouldn't take all that long. `[b for b in dir(__builtins__) if b == b.lower() and not b.startswith('_')]` contains just a few dozen entries, not all of which are functions.

Answer (score 1):

From Python 3.3

> New in version 3.3.

[**Introspecting callables with the Signature object**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#introspecting-callables-with-the-signature-object)

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.signature(sorted).parameters
mappingproxy(OrderedDict([('iterable', <Parameter "iterable">), ('key', <Parameter "key=None">), ('reverse', <Parameter "reverse=False">)]))
```

And then you can count them, and do whatever you like.

Comment: This isn't available in python 2.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard i mentioned it in answer. OP said: "It would be great if the solution work with both Python 2.7 and Python 3.3+", currently solution only for python 3.3+, which is ok, i think.

Answer (score 0):

You can somewhat do this, but only in Python 3. This is when `ArgumentClinic` made information about the signature of objects available.

Take note, not all built-ins are actually available as of right now, currently:

```
__import__ vars max print dir __build_class__ min iter round getattr next
```

do not expose information about their signature. For the rest `getargspec` (a thin wrapper around `getfullargspec`) and `Signature` would do.

In Python 2, you only have the option of `getargspec` which doesn't do the trick for built-ins and probably never will. So, there's no solution that spans across python versions. For the most compatible solution, I'd use `getargspec` as of right now.

As for the most simplistic way to check, just count the `args` from the `NamedTuple` returned:

```
def NumberOfParameters(f):
    try:
        r = getargspec(f)
        return len(r.args)  # if it has kwargs, what do you do?
    except TypeError as e:
        print("Function {0} cannot be inspected".format(f.__name__))
```